# handle large Parcelable ArrayList in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm developing an Android app that is a client to a JSON webservice API.

I have classes of resource objects (some are nested) and I pass results from an `IntentService` that access the webserive using the `Parcelable` interface for all the resource classes.

the webservice returns arrays or results that can be potentially large (because of the nesting, for example, a post object also contains comments array, each comment also contains a user object).

currently I'm either inserting the results into a SQlite database or displaying them in a `ListView`. (my relevant methods are accepting `ArrayList<resourceClass>` as arguments).
(some data need to be persistent stored and some should not).

since I don't know what size of lists I can handle this way without reaching the memory limits, is this a good practice ?

is it a better idea to save the parsed JSON to a local file immediately and pass the file path to the `ResultReceiver`, then either insert to database from that file or display the data ?

is there a better way to handle this ?

btw - I'm parsing the JSON as a stream with Gson's Reader so there shouldn't be memory issues at that stage.